# list() applied to zip object twice in a row issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, zip

I have built a zip object and by accident I noticed that if I apply list() to this object twice, second time it will yield []. My code is shown below:

```
coordinate = ['x', 'y', 'z']
values = [5, 7, 9]

my_map = zip(coordinate, values)

my_map_list_first = list(my_map)
my_map_list_second = list(my_map)

print(my_map_list_first)
print(my_map_list_second)
```

Output of the code is:

```
[('x', 5), ('y', 7), ('z', 9)]
[]
```

I am new to Python so my terminology may not be 100% accurate. I have tried finding the explanation online, but problem here is what is the actual question. (Good question makes half he answer). Since I am still learning Python, I probably don't know what to ask.

I also tried using that Python simulator which I saw in another topic:
http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display
But I only saw what I knew - that my_map_list_second is [], not what exactly is going on under the hood.
Can someone explain what happened here? And also point me in a right direction regarding "similar" issues, although I am sure those will become clear in time, as I progress with Python.

This is also my first port on these forums. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for awnser about [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators).

In fact, `zip` will create a `generator`, that is not process until you `iterate` trought it, using `list` in your exemple. An other important property is that `generator` can only be `iterate once`.

The last property explain why you get en empty list the second time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I obviously don't know about generators at this stage and info that you can iterate only once through it is useful,  I will have it in mind.
I knew that zip() creates a zip objects (which is iterable), but I didn't know what it in addition creates generator. I will go and read about it more now.

Comment: You are welcome, just to out in perspective, all generator are iterable, but not iterable are generator. But you have it, good luck in your learning journey.

Comment: Terminology nitpick: `zip` objects are not generators, but they are iterators.

Answer (score 6):

`zip` returns a `generator`, not `list`. `generator` only runs once, so you will need to recall `zip` again for `my_map_list_second`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know that zip doesn't return a list, but I didn't know about generators. I will now go and read about them.